# Filter users by using checkboxes for profile data in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, filter

I was looking over this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869679/using-checkboxes-to-filter-records) on using checkboxes to filter results in Rails but got kinda lost. I'm new to programming but want to filter Users on my index page depending on what profile data is checked in a sidebar. Ideally, the index page would start out with all Users, then filter down depending on the checkboxes. Here's relevant info from my User and Profile models, User controller, and the index.html.erb file:

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password, :email
  validates :email, :uniqueness => true, 
                :length => { :within => 5..50 }, 
                :format => { :with => /^[^@][\w.-]+@[\w.-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}$/i }
  validates :password, :confirmation => true,
                   :length => { :within => 4..20 },
                   :presence => true,
                   :if => :password_required?  
  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy
```

Profile model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :field_1, :field_2, :field_3, :field_4...
  belongs_to :user
```

User controller:

```
def index
  @user = User.all
end
```

Index.html.erb:

```
  <% form_for 'user' do |f| %>
  <table id="Criteria">
    <tr>
      <td class="main head">Fields</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="head">Field_1:</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="normal"><%= current_user.profile.field_1 %></td>
      <td><% check_box_tag :field_1 %></td>
    </tr>
```

If anyone can help explain it I'd appreciate it very much! (And if more info is needed let me know.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you should take a look at [Meta Search gem](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search). I used it to solve similar problem here http://omaris.kg/categories/2-zhenskaya-obuv

**UPD**

I have `Item` model where i defined scopes which filter items according to user request. Below is the scope which filter by brands:

```
scope :by_brands, lambda {|brands|
 brands = brands.delete_if {|i| i == "" } if brands.present?
 return if brands.blank?
 composed = self.scoped

 composed = composed.where("brand_id IN (?)", brands)
 composed
}
```

Then i created **class** method `searchy(search)` (didn't find any better name XD) where i call every scope one after another like `self.by_brands(search[:brands]).by_price_range(search[:from], search[:to])...`
`search` parameter is going to be `params[:searchy]`

Then i used like `Item.searchy(params[:search])` in my controller. `params[:searchy]` are got from `form_for` block in the view.

That's it, i guess )

P.S.: For the first time i wanted to use MetaSearch gem to use its heplers in my form. But i did without it and build my own

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping for a solution that didn't require a gem though so I could learn more.

Comment: Could you post a bit of code as an example of how you implemented your solution?

Comment: Thanks. Is it bad practice to have eight separate scopes?